# Flicker removal using OpenCV?

Tags: opencv, flicker

I am a newbie to openCV. I have installed the opencv library on a ubuntu system, compiled it and trying to look into some image/video processing apps in opencv to understand more.

I am interested to know if OpenCV library has any algorithm/class for removal flicker in captured videos? If yes what document or code should I should look deeper into?

If openCV does not have it, are there any standard implementations in some other Video processing library/SDK/Matlab,.. which provide algorithms for flicker removal from video sequences?

Any pointers would be useful

Thank you.

-AD.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know any standard way to deflicker a video.

But [VirtualDub](http://www.virtualdub.org/) is a Video Processing software which has a Filter for deflickering the video. You can find it's filter source and documents (algorithm description probably) [here](http://neuron2.net/deflick/flick.html).

Answer (score 2):

I wrote my own Deflicker C++ function.  here it is.  You can cut and paste this code as is - no headers needed other than the usual openCV ones.

```
    Mat deflicker(Mat,int);
    Mat prevdeflicker;
    Mat deflicker(Mat Mat1,int strengthcutoff = 20){  //deflicker - compares each pixel of the frame to a previously stored frame, and throttle small changes in pixels (flicker)

    if (prevdeflicker.rows){//check if we stored a previous frame of this name.//if not, theres nothing we can do. clone and exit
         int i,j;
        uchar* p;
        uchar* prevp;
        for( i = 0; i < Mat1.rows; ++i)
        {
            p = Mat1.ptr<uchar>(i);
            prevp = prevdeflicker.ptr<uchar>(i);
            for ( j = 0; j < Mat1.cols; ++j){  

                Scalar previntensity = prevp[j];
                Scalar intensity = p[j];
                int strength = abs(intensity.val[0] - previntensity.val[0]);

                if(strength < strengthcutoff){ //the strength of the stimulus must be greater than a certain point, else we do not want to allow the change
                    //value 25 works good for medium+ light.  anything higher creates too much blur around moving objects. 
                    //in low light however this makes it worse, since low light seems to increase contrasts in flicker - some flickers go from 0 to 255 and back.  :(
                    //I need to write a way to track large group movements vs small pixels, and only filter out the small pixel stuff.  maybe blur first?

                    if(intensity.val[0] > previntensity.val[0]){  // use the previous frames value.  Change it by +1 - slow enough to not be noticable flicker
                        p[j] = previntensity.val[0] + 1;  
                    }else{
                        p[j] = previntensity.val[0] - 1;
                    }
                }

            }

        }//end for
    }

    prevdeflicker = Mat1.clone();//clone the current one as the old one.
    return Mat1;
}
```

Call it as: Mat= deflicker(Mat).  It needs a loop, and a greyscale image, like so:

```
for(;;){
    cap >> frame; // get a new frame from camera
    cvtColor( frame, src_grey, CV_RGB2GRAY );  //convert to greyscale - simplifies everything

    src_grey = deflicker(src_grey);  // this is the function call

    imshow("grey video", src_grey);
    if(waitKey(30) >= 0) break;
}
```